Show the list chromatic number of complete r-partite graph is r
I encountered a problem as follows,
Let $G$ be a complete $r$-partite graph with all parts of size $2$. (In other words, $G$
is $K_{2r}$ minus a perfect matching.) Show that $\chi_{l}(G) = r$, where $\chi_{l}(G)$ is the list chromatic number of it.
I know how to prove if within each part, there are no sharing colors. (Using Hall's theorem). Here I mean suppose $A_{1}, \cdots A_{r}$ are the $r$ parts, $A_{i}=\{a_i,b_i\}$, then $\forall i, L(a_i) \cap L(b_i)=\emptyset$, where $L(a_i), L(b_i)$ are the color list for $a_i$ and $b_i$.
But I get lost when there exists a part sharing colors.

(Note on the duplicate: the question there is primarily for the part that you understand, using Hall's theorem. However, the body of the question, and the answer by Asinomás, cover the other case - the one you have trouble with.)
